# Get the immediate values from the adjacent columns based on the value of another column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I want to find the person that ate the most tacos from a taco eating competition.

DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tacos':[5,10,7]},index=['John','Carlos','Peter'])
```

If I have identified the max tacos a person has eaten, then how I could get the name of that person as a string?

```
maxtacos = df['Tacos'].max()


df.get(df[Name], df['Tacos', maxtacos])
```

I would like to get "Carlos" as a result.

Thank you

Comment: `df.loc[df['Tacos'].eq(df['Tacos'].max(), 'Name'].tolist()` You can have more than one person...

Comment: This is returning the complete row with all the columns, instead, I would like to get "Carlos" as a string.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can have more than one person who ate the max number of tacos, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'Tacos': [5, 5, 1], 'Name': ['John', 'Harry', 'Bill']})`.  Note that `idxmax` only gives you the _first_ name that matches the max value, the method above gives you the list of all names, i.e. `df.loc[df['Tacos'].eq(df['Tacos'].max()), 'Name'].tolist()` results in `['John', 'Harry']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you should be able to use `df.idxmax()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tacos':[5,10,7]},index=['John','Carlos','Peter'])
df.idxmax()
```

That will return Carlos in this example.

Now, if you want the value of another column, you could do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tacos':[5,10,7],'beers':[1,2,3]},index=['John','Carlos','Peter'])
df['beers'].loc[df['tacos'].idxmax()]
```

That would tell you that the person who ate the most tacos drank 2 beers.

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I wanted to know. Is there any place with a list of all these functions and a description of them?

Comment: You can get the dataframe methods in the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)